# Integrating $\int \coth(x)\left(\pi^{\ln(\sinh^2x)}+\tanh^2x\right)dx$

Tags: integration

I'm new to the topic and I'm having a hard time solving solving this:

$$\int \coth(x)\left(\pi^{\ln(\sinh^2x)}+\tanh^2x\right)dx$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. What ideas are you allowed to use? For instance, I’ve come up with a series solution...

Comment: Hi. I'm not familiar with the series solution. Can the rule of substitution be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substituting $\sinh x = u$. We get

$\displaystyle \tag*{} \begin{align} I &= \int \frac{\pi^{\ln u^2}}{u} \ du + \int \frac{u}{1+u^2} \ du \\ &= \frac{\pi^{\ln u^2}}{\ln \pi^2} + \frac{\ln (u^2+1)}{2} + \text{constant}\end{align} $

Hence, we get the integral as
$\displaystyle \tag*{} \frac{\pi^{\ln \sinh^2 x}}{\ln \pi^2} + \ln (\cosh x) + \text{constant} $